# How can we call a function in a module and get the result in the Main thread asynchronously in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a function in a module that returns a datatable.  I need to call that function asynchronously and get the results in the Main thread (Main Form) in vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `BackgroundWorker` to do this.

`Private WithEvents dataBackgroundWorker As New BackgroundWorker`

Then you would need to call

`dataBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`

Which raises the `DoWork` Event

So in that handler you would call your function and return it through the `e.Result`

`e.Result = yourFunction()`

then in the `RunWorkerCompleted` Event you would assign `e.Result` to the appropriate variable.

Comment: Thank you. I am not able to return the datatable as e.result and get the datatable in RunWorkerCompleted  event. Can you please help? It throws an exception nullable object must have a value. I can set the string as result

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to use the background worker.  If you are feeling adventurous though, the Async CTP looks pretty awesome.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360

You can find samples here:  http://www.wischik.com/lu/AsyncSilverlight/AsyncSamples.html

```
Public Async Function AsyncResponsiveCPURun() As Task
    Console.WriteLine("Processing data...  Drag the window around or scroll the tree!")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Dim data As Integer() = Await ProcessDataAsync(GetData(), 16, 16)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Processing complete.")
End Function


Public Function ProcessDataAsync(ByVal data As Byte(), ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Task(Of Integer())
    Return TaskEx.Run(
        Function()
            Dim result(width * height) As Integer
            For y As Integer = 0 To height - 1
                For x As Integer = 0 To width - 1
                    Thread.Sleep(10)   ' simulate processing cell [x,y]
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("Processed row {0}", y)
            Next
            Return result
        End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: It does look awesome. I believe the terms and conditions say that you aren't meant to deploy it in production code... while I can't recommend that you contravene that legal agreement, I believe it is the only thing that stands in the way, nothing technical (besides it not being supported)